# What is the "standard dialect form" of どないも?

Tags: meaning, kansai-ben

> えっ、私が運転手ですか
> ああ、社長専属の運転手が体調を崩してどないもアカンらしいねん

My attempt at a translation:

> *Huh, me a driver?
>
> Yes, the president's personal driver is not feeling good*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard dialect, "[どない](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/)" would be "どう", "どんな(に)" or "どのよう(に)".

And "どないも" would be "[どうにも](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82/)", meaning "no matter what", "for one's life", "if one's life depended on it", etc.

So the line translates to something like

> Yeah, I'm hearing the president's driver isn't feeling well and no good (for work) if his life depended on it.